# POST response gives error: "The JSON value could not be converted to api.Models.Account"

Tags: javascript, c#, json, post, controller

I'm having an error between sending a JSON POST request to my C# .NET backend controller, which gives me a POST error code 400, which I understand to mean bad request.
I prompt the user (a fitness trainer at a gym) for information for a new training session, which looks like this (extra code removed for concision):

```
class Session {
    int SessionID;
    string Title;
    string ExerciseType;
    Account Trainer;
    Account[] Trainees;
    DateTime DateTime;
}
```

here is the `Account` class, which, like `Session`, is in the Models namespace / directory mentioned in the error:

```
class Account {
    string Username;
    string Password;
    string FName;
    string LName;
    string Type;
}
```

my `SessionController`'s POST method:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody] Session session) {
    Console.WriteLine("Post reached. session is " + session.ToString());
}
```

I understand that my JSON is not formatted correctly to be fit into a `Session` object. My error is telling me that controller cannot accept the JSON that is being sent by my POST request:

```
fetch(api/url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Accept": 'application/json',
        "Content-Type": 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        Title : title,
        ExerciseType: category,
        Trainer: JSON.stringify({
            Username: sessionStorage.loginUsername,
            Password: null,
            FName: sessionStorage.loginfName,
            LName: sessionStorage.loginlName,
            Type: sessionStorage.loginType
        }),
        DateTime: datetime
    })
}).catch(function(error, cont..));
```

I've tried mixtures of using `JSON.stringify()` in some places and not others, or not all, but I always get javascript errors - it seems this is the furthest I can get. Could someone help me nest my `Account` object inside the session payload?

Edit: In the end, I really only need to send the username of the trainer hosting the session. Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I retried just now and there are no errors and my data appears in the database. No idea what was happening before, as I haven't changed anything.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a single JSON.stringify on the outermost object should suffice in the fetch (POST) request body

```js
body: JSON.stringify({
    Title : title,
    ExerciseType: category,
    Trainer: {
        Username: sessionStorage.loginUsername,
        Password: null,
        FName: sessionStorage.loginfName,
        LName: sessionStorage.loginlName,
        Type: sessionStorage.loginType
    },
    DateTime: datetime,
    Duration: duration,
    Capacity: capacity,
    Rate: rate
})
```

I also noticed you have some additional fields in your json object that do not exist on the .NET model like Duration, Capacity and Rate (I'll advice you ensure the .NET model also captures these).

Comment: With this, I get an error: `Unexpected end of JSON input`